# Scout crash at launching SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-scout, linkageerror

I have some strange error in Scout Eclipse. My college push some cone in git and I pull it out. On his computer everything works well, but on mine it's get error when launching SWT.

Error is :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2014-06-26 09:44:21.234
!MESSAGE Unable to create class'org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon' from bundle '72'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingTable.addBinding(Lorg/eclipse/jface/bindings/Binding;)V" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/swt/util/BindingProcessingAddon, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/eclipse/e4/ui/bindings/internal/BindingTable, have different Class objects for the type org/eclipse/jface/bindings/Binding used in the signature
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:877)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:267)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:276)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:581)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at com.sixt.test.ldaplogintwo.ui.swt.application.Application.startSecure(Application.java:35)
at com.sixt.test.ldaplogintwo.ui.swt.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:27)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at com.sixt.test.ldaplogintwo.ui.swt.application.Application.start(Application.java:24)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingTable.addBinding(Lorg/eclipse/jface/bindings/Binding;)V" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/swt/util/BindingProcessingAddon, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/eclipse/e4/ui/bindings/internal/BindingTable, have different Class objects for the type org/eclipse/jface/bindings/Binding used in the signature
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.defineBinding(BindingProcessingAddon.java:184)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.defineBindingTable(BindingProcessingAddon.java:168)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.defineBindingTables(BindingProcessingAddon.java:151)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.init(BindingProcessingAddon.java:100)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
... 31 more
```

I really try to make it works but I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Possibly related to Eclipse bug [376667](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376667) which seems to be caused by having two versions of the `org.eclipse.jface` plugin in the target platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*== Ensure you are using the same target Platform as your colleague*

Open **Preferences > Plug-in development > Target Platform**. You should have the same active target platform definition.

If you use running platform as active target definition, you should have exaclty the same Eclipse IDE installation to be able to compare.

*== Ensure you start the application the same way*

Open the client product file for example:

```
/<your-app>.ui.swt/products/development/<app>-swt-client-dev.product
```

Click on the **Synchronize** link in the testing section in the overview tab. (sometime you need to do this operation twice).

Start the application with the run or debug button in the same section.

[image: Eclipse product file editor]

*== Test an other scout application on your computer*

To determine if your eclipse scout IDE installation is OK or not, what happend when you create a test application in an other workspace? Do you manage to start it?

*== Verify the content of your target platform*

@marko-zadravec suggested to verify if you do not have 2 version of `org.eclipse.jface` in your target platform.

In the "Target Platform" preference page, select your active target definition in the list and click on the **Edit** button.

Switch to the **Content** tab. Check if you havent two `org.eclipse.jface` bundles.

*== Reinstall the IDE*

Sometimes reinstalling **Eclipse for Scout Developers** is the quickest solution to solve those kind of problems (Go to the [Eclipse Downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index.php) page).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I did is to reinstall scout and from this point on everything work :D

Comment: Yes sometimes reinstalling “Eclipse for Scout Developers” helps. I will add this idea to my answer. Do not forget to vote up my answer and to select it to mark your question as closed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and just wanted to let the fix registered here.

I opened the file **bundles.info** located in 
`*<Eclipse_install_folder*>\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\`

I searched for **rap.jface**, deleted everything that was found and saved the file.

Then the Eclipse was able to start again.

I was using Eclipse Mars by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well and fix it by removing the `org.eclipse.rap.jface` plugin dependency in the client product file.

That should do the trick (at least for us because we have only SWT clients).

~Serano